# Delete answer with no apparent reason

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Recently I answered a question about a serious problem with the Facebook PHP auth2.0 invalid token issue. A Moderator deleted my answer.

I am just trying to find out what is going on. I was communicating with the user but suddenly he tells me that he cannot see the answer. When I checked, I saw that it was deleted. But why?

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20313824/).

Comment: Please provide a link to the question/answer.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20313779/969613)?

Comment: Yeap sorry guys forgot it.

Comment: Unrelated: did you report the bug to Facebook? If not, please do so (assuming it actually is a bug).

Comment: @Felix yes there is a pull request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Three of your answers were identified as cut/paste duplicates by the system.

Questions that can be answered with identical verbiage are extremely rare.  Either the questions are duplicates, or the answerer is carpet-bombing.

Note that the first answer I encountered on your account was to a question that is almost two years old.

I undeleted your cited answer, and closed the other two questions as duplicates of the highest voted one.

Comment: The questions even 1 year old where not resolved. There was an issue with the php dsk and I had to update 2-3 answers to questions with almost the same text. Next time I want do it. But now how should I proceed?

Comment: Vote to close as duplicates the questions that are duplicates, and post your answer once to the "master" question.

Comment: They are not exact duplicates.

Comment: Then make your answers unique for each one.

Comment: @JimmyKane: If two questions are solved by the same solution, then they are duplicates.

Comment: @Felix: No, that's not true.  We don't evaluate answers when checking for question duplicates (for the most part), and two completely different questions can have the same solution.

Comment: So  there are 2 same answers on 2 posts. The one deleted is the one that is important. How can we undo this? The other one is indeed inactive.

Comment: @Robert: True, this was too general. But often such questions have the same core problem, even if the specific use case is different.

Comment: @JimmyKane Why are they not duplicates?  They are different cases of a single bug cropping up, indicating the same problem, and they all have the same fix.  Clearly whatever differences there are between the questions are not germane to the answer (since you felt a single answer answered all of those questions) so they can be duplicates.  Either that, or your answer doesn't adequately answer all of the questions because the problem or the solution is slightly different in each case.

Comment: @Servy and Robert thanks guys for the info and the explanation. Keep up the good work. Have a great day.

Comment: @JimmyKane Kudos for the constructive question and wanting advice. Robert has covered anything I would say here (For others' information; I'm the one who deleted the answer in question here)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Regarding your advice to "Vote to close as duplicates the questions that are duplicates, and post your answer once to the "master" question.", and noting that I don't know what the duplicate questions are in this case, this isn't always possible.  Trying to close a question as a duplicate of can result in the message "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer".  This can be a problem in tags with low readership, where a user might not accept, and no one has upvoted yet.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: That didn't happen here.